# Cannot locate textures in XNA

Tags: svn, xna

I've been working on this game with friends using tortoise SVN over at his house. I moved my computer back home and exported it so it was no longer connected to the repository and since then none of my textures will load when I run the program. I've checked my files and they are pointing to the right place. even after deleting and adding them back into my game content I still get the same thing.

A screen shot of my problem... https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wb4uw.jpg

You can clearly see the path is correct and i'm calling it correctly otherwise it wouldn't of worked the hundred other times I ran it. Hope someone can help. I'm not even sure if it has anything to do with SVN or not.

Comment: Are you referencing the content project in your game? Also setting content director? eg, 'Content.RootDirectory = "Content";'

Comment: Furthermore, the content project must have been built and you should find the output files in the bin directory (mostly .xnb files). It may be that the output directory of the content project is set to an absolute path on your old machine.

Comment: Apologies for not checking this sooner. Thanks @Nico. I checked the bin directory and the .xnb files where not to be found. I created a full new solution and moved everything across and it created the .xnb files for me.